# Как узнать превысила ширина текста ширину QLabel?

Tags: qt, qt5, pyside2

QLabel имеет фиксированную ширину, и если тест не помещается в ширину надо обрезаеть его и добавить многоточие (так часто делают, все могли видеть), например:

```
Это короткий текст
Это длинный длинный длинн...
```

Как узнать, превысила ширина текста заданную ширину?

Пока что мысли считать кол-во символов, и если оно превышает кол-во символов, которое помещается в фиксированную ширину, делать процедуры с обрезанием.  Но тут меня беспокоят 2 момента:

1. Символы не одинаковой ширины, например "1" и "ш", отсюда могут бывать косяки.
2. Мониторы с разным разрешением и DPI, символы же могут по разному отображаться?  Увы у меня всего 1 монитор и проверить не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html). Пример использования:

```
QFontMetrics fm(label.font());
int pixelsWide = fm.horizontalAdvance("What's the width of this text?");
int pixelsHigh = fm.height();
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло.